# how to convert string day into date time format in php

Tags: php

I got an output like this, I am doing it in php :

```
Tue Jul 12 09:48:44 2016
```

I want to convert it into like this :

```
2016-07-12 09:48:44
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below code

```
$date = 'Tue Jul 12 09:48:44 2016';
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($date));
```

**Output:**
2016-07-12 09:48:44

Answer (score 2):

Use `date()` function to change date time format and don’t forget to use `strtotime()`

```
date ("Y-m-d h:i:s",strtotime("Tue Jul 12 09:48:44 2016"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd parse the input with createFromFormat:-

```
$dateInputString = "Tue Jul 12 09:48:44 2016";

//Convert the string from the format supplied to a date
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D M d H:i:s Y', $dateInputString);

//output the date in the required format
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```